# In Futures.transform, what is the difference between using a Function and an AsyncFunction

Tags: java, guava, future, concurrent.futures

I know that the apply method of Function returns an object synchronously, and the apply of AsyncFunction runs asynchronously and returns a Future.

Can you give me an example of when to prefer what.

One code snippet that I saw looked something like this:

```
Futures.transform(someFuture, new AsyncFunction<A, B>() {
  public B apply(A a) {
    if (a != null) {
      return Futures.immediateFuture(a.getData())
    } else {
      return Futures.immediateFailedFuture(checkException(());
    }
  });
});
```

Since the value inside AsyncFunction is returned as immediate result, why is AsyncFunction needed here? Or is this just a bad example that I came across?

Comment: Do you know what synchronous and asynchronous mean in this context? Explain them to us.

Comment: One waits to complete the operation before returning the value, and the other immediately returns a placeholder, that will have the result of the operation at some point of time.

Comment: Great. So an example of each is when you need either of those behaviors.

Comment: I have seen some code snippets that looks like this: Futures.transform(someFuture, new AsyncFunction<A, B>() { public B apply(A a) {//converts a to B} }); And here the function inside the apply methos is actually not a long running function at all. So why is AsyncFunction required here? Or was this a bad example that I saw

Comment: Added the edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: As a clarification, what does `a.getData` return? And what is `B`? And what is `someFuture`?

Comment: Did you mean to have the method return a `ListenableFuture<B>`?

Answer (score 10):

The code snippet you found is a bad example, since it uses an AsyncFunction for something that is computed synchronously. It's needlessly verbose.

The code would be cleaner using a standard `Function`:

```
Futures.transform(someFuture, new Function<A, B>() {
  public B apply(A a) {
    if (a != null) {
      return a.getData();
    } else {
      throw checkException();
    }
  });
});
```

You should use an `AsyncFunction` when the code that transforms A to B is asynchronous. In your example, it's possible that the code was asynchronous at first, and was later changed to use `Futures.immediateFuture()` / `Futures.immediateFailedFuture()` by a programmer who didn't bother replacing the `AsyncFunction` with a `Function`. Or maybe he just missed the overloaded method.

Comment: I'm missing something. How do you tell that the code that transforms A to B is/should be synchronous?

Comment: It just depends on how you transform A to B. If transforming A to B needs some asynchronous I/O or WS call, you'll have to use an AsyncFunction that returns a `Future`. In the example given, the use of `Futures.immediateFuture()` / `Futures.immediateFailedFuture()` denotes a synchronous transformation. Keep in mind that I'm only talking about the synchronicity of the transforming function, since the computation of "someFuture" is probably asynchronous.

Comment: We don't know what `a.getData()` does so I still don't see why you make the assumption that it is synchronous. I think `Futures.immediateFuture` is just used to wrap the result of `a.getData()` because the `apply` method needs to return a `ListenableFuture`. The result of `a.getData()` has to be calculated before that `ListenableFuture` is returned. So, `Futures.immediateFuture` is synchronous relative to `a.getData`, but the `transform` call is asynchronous relative to the `AsyncFunction` and vice versa. (Note that OP's code doesn't seem to compile.)

Comment: Futures.immediateFuture() is a blocking call. It creates a Future, but in the same thread as it is being called, which is how we know that the example is synchronous.

Comment: @CliveEvans Yeah, but that happens within an `AsyncFunction`, which happens in a separate thread.

Comment: I might have misused the word "synchronous". I should have said "blocking". What I meant, is that whatever `a.getData()` does, using `Futures.immediateFuture(a.getData())` will block until `getData()` returns. The code inside `getData()` itself might be asynchronous, call a WS on the other side of the planet asynchronously, but if it's not returning a future, it will block. In such a case, using an AsyncFunction is useless.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how the `transform` uses the `AsyncFunction`. Does it not submit the `AsyncFuntion` to be done in a separate thread? In this case, what does it matter if `immediateFuture` is blocking? It's still done in a different thread.

Comment: Having code that blocks on synchronous I/O is bad, even if it is done in a different thread. It's still a JVM thread that's uselessly blocking. Also, unless you specify an Executor, I believe the AsyncFunction is executed in the thread that completes the input Future, which might be problematic.

Comment: `immediateFuture` simply returns an `ImmediateSuccessfulFuture` which has its value set immediately, in this case with the return value of `a.getData()`. What do you mean by blocking here? If this is done in a separate `AsyncFunction` thread (which, sure, might need a custom `Executor` specified), then no threads are blocked until the calling thread invokes `ListenableFuture#get()`. Please response with `@myname` so I can get notified.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I meant that it might block on the call to `a.getData()`. I don't think it does in this case, since it's probably a simple getter. But you wrote in a previous comment "We don't know what a.getData() does so I still don't see why you make the assumption that it is synchronous.", so I thought we were discussing that. Yes, `immediateFuture()` returns immediately, but it won't be called until `getData()` completes. So this code blocks on `getData()`. If `getData()` is indeed asynchronous, it should be fixed to return a `Future`, and `immediateFuture()` becomes useless.

Comment: Yeah, but what does that have to do with anything? As I stated earlier, `immediateFuture` is just to wrap the value of `a.getData` in a `ListenableFuture` which is the type expected by the `apply` method. It seems OP's code doesn't compile.

Comment: I don't think the issue here is the `immediateFuture`, it's the fact that the `AsyncFunction` was used without an `Executor`. As you stated earlier, if you don't submit an `Executor` it uses the same thread to apply the function.

Answer (score 3):

> Since the value inside AsyncFunction is returned as immediate result,
>   why is AsyncFunction needed here? Or is this just a bad example that I
>   came across?

Careful. That piece of code is generating an instance of an anonymous class and passing that instance to the `transform` method. The `transform` method will use the `AsyncFunction` is a separate thread. The `Future` returned chains to retrieve the results from the `AsyncFunction` and return the result of that `Future`. This code still involves asynchronous processing.

Use asynchronous processing when you want to and can continue doing work while something else is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you gave is a bad example, whoever wrote it should have used Function.

Futures.transform() is used to follow up on some asynchronous process. Lets call it "ap1" for "asynchronous process 1". When ap1 is done, the function chained by transform will execute.
Now, lets discuss the 2 types of functions you can chain with Futures.transform().

```
    // AsyncFunction() example:
    ListenableFuture<B> future2 = Futures.transform(future1, new AsyncFunction<A, B>() {
      public ListenableFuture<B> apply(A a) {
        if (a != null) {
          ListenableFuture<B> future3 = asyncCallToOtherService(a);
          return future3;
        }
        else {
          return Future.immediateFuture(null);
        }
      });
    });

    // more complex AsyncFunction() example:
    ListenableFuture<B> future2 = Futures.transform(future1, new AsyncFunction<A, B>() {
      public ListenableFuture<B> apply(A a) {
        if (a != null) {
          ListenableFuture<C> future3 = asyncCallToOtherService(a);
          return Futures.transform(future3, new Function<C, B>() {
            @Override
            public B apply(C c) {
              B b = new B();
              b.setResult(c.getStatus());
              return b;
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          return Future.immediateFuture(null);
        }
      });
    });

    // Function() example:
    ListenableFuture<B> future2 = Futures.transform(future1, new Function<A, B>() {
      public B apply(A a) {
        if (a != null) {
          B b = new B();
          b.setResult(a.getStatus());
          return b;
        }
        else {
          return null;
        }
      });
    });
```

1. AsyncFunction() should be used when the code inside the apply() spawns another asynchronous process 2 (AP2). This forms a sequence of asynchronous calls that follow each other: AP1->AP2.
2. Function() should be used when the transformation of the result from AP1 does not require any additional asynchronous processes. Rather all it does is translate the result Object1 into some other Object2 in a synchronous manner.
3. AsyncFunction() is slightly heavier and results in separate thread, therefore we should use Function() whenever we don't need to spin AP2.
4. Multiple Functions and AsyncFunctions can be chained together as needed in order to make a complete workflow. The example "more complex AsyncFunction() example" chains A~>C->B transformations, with A~>C being asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Using AsyncFunction makes sense here. If you want to throw some checked exception out of the apply() method in Function, it would complain it's not handled. You can not throw it out of the apply() for it's overridden. So If you want to throw some checked exception, AsyncFunction should be a valid solution. For those saying the given example is bad and given Function example, can you please try compile it?